# How can I force login with the OAuth API?

Tags: oauth, facebook-oauth

Is there a parameter I can pass to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth that will force the user to login again?

The problem is if the user is logged into Facebook, it will redirect transparently back to my site, even if the user wants to use a different Facebook account.

Twitter's OAuth API accepts a "force_redirect=true" parameter which does what I want, but I can't find one for Facebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think "auth_type=reauthenticate" is the option you are looking for.

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reauthentication/

Comment: They hid it so well!  That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: That's not a solution anymore. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289240/reauthenticate-feature-has-changed-its-behavior

Comment: I see a site forcing me to log in right now even though I'm already logged in to Facebook, so there must be a way to do this. It doesn't look to me like auth_type is even being passed.