# reauthenticate feature has changed its behavior?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-oauth

In my application to be able to switch to another user, I use the **"auth_type=reauthenticate"** parameter for the "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" URL. This worked for a long time. I was able to log in using other FB user than last logged. (e.g. shared PC)
Today I found out that there is no longer possible to change the user. Only re-enter password. Moreover, there is no "Cancel" button (used "dispalay=popup").

I can't find something about it on developers.facebook.com

Is anybody know something about it? Is it temporary bug or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

from : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/

Note that **apps should build their own mechanisms for allowing switching between different Facebook user accounts** using log out functions and should not rely upon re-authentication for this.

Comment: The issue here is not the apps mechanisms to allow switching users, it's FB API. I have an application and I want to force a user switch. FB API does not offer any way to logout users. If I'm already logged in, the login form automatically closes and grants me an access token, not giving me the option to switch or logout users.

Comment: @GerardoContijoch Did you manage to find out a solution? I ran the same problem for my app which needed to logout the current user to allow login with different accounts.